Calculating Expected Value for a Carnival Game
There is a carnival game of pure luck, and there are $2$ prizes. One is a jackpot with a $67/63000$ chance of happening, and a smaller prize with a chance of $25/216$ of happening. The player must pay $\$5$ to play the game once. The owner of the carnival game should win $3\%$ of the player's money on average (not a fair game).
How much should the prizes be to match this $3\%$ profit? The prize for hitting the jackpot should be
$100$* larger than that of the smaller prize, hence the names.
I tried calculating finding this out like this, with $x$ being the amount of money the player would earn if they get the smaller prize: $E(x) = 25x/216 + 6700x/63000 - 5$
I multiplied the amount of money gained from the jackpot prize by $100$ compared to the smaller prize so that it is $100$* larger of a prize, as specified in the details. I subtracted $5$ as that is the price to play the game.
Also, since I want the player to lose $3\%$ of their money, I know the expected value is $15$ cents $(5*0.03=0.15)$.
Then I added the fractions together with a common denominator $(189000)$:
$-0.15 = (25x(875)+6700x(3))/189000 - 5$
$-0.15 = (21875x+20100x)/189000 - 5$
$-0.15 = 41975x/189000 - 5$
$-0.15 = 1679x/7560 - 5$
$-1134 = 1679x - 5$
$-1129 = 1679x$
$-1120/1679 = x$
$x = 0.66$
Is this correct? Or am I doing something wrong?

Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match many users' quality standards, so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. This will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Your basic equation,
$-0.15 = (21875x+20100x)/189000 - 5$ is correct,
as are your steps upto
$-0.15 = 1679x/7560 - 5$
You have then committed the mistake of multiplying by $7560$, the $-0.15$ term on the LHS but not doing so for the $-5$ on the RHS
Alternatively, by transferring $-5$ to LHS, you would have got
$4.85 = 1679x/7560$
which yields an answer of $21.838$, ie $\boxed{\$21.84}$ to the nearesr cent
As a double check (as I am getting a different answer from a posted one)
feeding the basic equation (which I have checked) to wolfram, the answer is confirmed.

I am answering this question because it looks like the work shown by the original poster in editing the question has sufficiently improved the quality of the question.
I will assume the unit of measurement of $~1\$~$ throughout this answer.
I approach the problem somewhat differently than the original poster did.  That is, I:

Want the expected return to the player to be $~(0.97 \times 5) = 4.85.$

Compute the value of $~x,~$ the size of the smaller prize, in terms of  fixed but unspecified probability constants, $~p_1~$ and $~p_2.$ 
Then, I simply plug in the values of $~p_1 = \dfrac{67}{63000},~$ and $~p_2 = \dfrac{25}{216},~$ and then compute the exactly value of $~x.$



Let $~p_1~$ denote the probability of winning the grand prize of $~100x.$
Let $~p_2~$ denote the probability of winning the second prize of $~x.$
Also, for simplicity, assume that $~p_1,p_2~$ are fixed constants such that $~0 < p_1, p_2 < 1.$
Then, the expected value of the $~5~$ investment is
$$[ ~p_1 \times 100x ~] + [ ~p_2 \times x ~]$$
$$= x \times ( ~100p_1 + p_2 ~). \tag1 $$
In order for the carnival owner to win $~3\%~$ of the $~5,~$ the expected value must be $~4.85.$
Therefore, using (1) above, you have that
$$x = \dfrac{4.85}{100p_1 + p_2}. \tag2 $$
Note that
$$100p_1 + p_2 = \dfrac{67}{630} + \frac{25}{216}$$
$$= \frac{1}{2} \times \left[ ~\frac{67}{315} + \frac{25}{128} ~\right] \tag3 $$
$$= \frac{1}{2} \times \frac{(~67 \times 128~) + (~25 \times 315 ~)}{315 \times 128} $$
$$= \frac{1}{2} \times \frac{16451}{40320} = \frac{16451}{80640}.$$
Therefore,
$$x = \frac{4.85}{\frac{16451}{80640}} = \frac{4.85 \times 80640}{16451} \approx 23.77.$$

$~\underline{\text{Sanity Checking}}$
If you examine the computation marked (3) above, you will see that (very loosely)
$$100p_1 + p_2 \approx \frac{1}{2} \times \left[ ~\frac{1}{5} + \frac{1}{5} ~\right] \approx \frac{1}{5}.$$
Therefore, intuitively, you would expect
$$x \approx \frac{4.85}{1/5} = 5 \times 4.85.$$
